# Особенности церковнославянского и старославянского языков

Tags: история, славянские-языки

Скажите, пожалуйста, чем церковнославянский язык отличается от старославянского?
И есть ли вообще отличия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Старославянский язык** — древнейший известный славянский **литературный** язык, созданный во второй половине IX в.Кириллом и Мефодием для нужд христианской православной церкви. Диалектной основой старославянского языка стал один из говоров южных славян — солунский диалект, на котором говорили Кирилл и Мефодий, поскольку именно он был распространен в окрестностях их родной Фессалоники. В те времена различия между славянскими языками были ещё невелики, поэтому старославянский язык мог претендовать на роль *общеславянского литературного языка*. Термин **«старославянский»** является наиболее принятым в современной русскоязычной науке; аналогично образованы термины фр. le vieux slave, лат. palaeoslavica. В разных лингвистических традициях старославянский язык называется: древнецерковнославянский (в русской традиции XIX — начала XX веков, нем. Altkirchenslavisch, англ. Old Church Slavonic), древнеславянский (Н. И. Толстой, Ф. Мареш, Н. А. Мещерский, М. М. Копыленко), древне- или староболгарский (в болгарской традиции, иногда в немецкой: Altbulgarisch). До середины XIX века в русской традиции назывался (вместе с церковнославянским) просто «словенским», «славенским» или «славянщиной» (у Ломоносова, Шишкова и др).

**Церковнославянский язык** — одна из современных форм старославянского языка, употребляемая в основном в православном богослужении. Церковнославянский язык никогда не был разговорным (на нём мог общаться только узкий круг образованных людей).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Оба языка не были разговорными. Область применения старославянского языка - шире: не только церковный обиход, но и создание литературы (напр., поучений), летописей и пр. При этом в старославянский язык всегда примешивались элементы разговорного языка восточных славян (на соответствующей территории), поскольку существовали они параллельно. Авторы и переписчики были носителями каких-то диалектов, особенности которых они иногда отражали на письме. Древнецерковнославянский же в этом отношении более строго соблюдал установленные нормы (язык богослужений более консервативен, отступать от образца было нельзя). Но корень у них один - солунский диалект, на котором говорили Кирилл и Мефодий. Созданный ими язык был предназначен для нужд христианской православной церкви, а потом стал использоваться шире. Таким образом язык развился в двух вариантах - церковнославянский и старославянский.

Comment: Только не совсем понятно. Сначала написано, что церковнославянский никогда не был разговорным, а потом, что старославянский — и есть церковнославянский. Значит, разговорным он все-таки был?  
А если не был, то в чем отличия?

Answer (score 1):

Очень странная формулировка. Как это живой на тот момент язык "был создан"?
Да и из истории извесно, что солунские братья создали не язык, а письменность (опускаю "свидетельства" надписях древних укров на стенах египетских пирамид).

На самом деле здесь действительно некоторый разнобой в терминологии. Большинство всё-таки склонно называть "старославянским" единый на момент первой письменной фиксации язык всех славян. Если совсем точно: ещё единый, но уже находящийся в стадии распада. Диалектами ("изводами") тогдашнего старославянского языка были древнерусский, древнеболгарский, западнославянский (моравский) и другие. В то же время один из этих диалектов - древнеболгарский - тоже часто называют старославянским языком. Этот язык был тогда ещё понятен всем без исключения славянам - и на нём велись богослужения после христианизации основной массы славянского населения Балкан. Поэтому этот диалект стал так же называться церковнословянским, хотя обычно этот термин обычно используется в отношении современного состояния языка. Хотя, насколько могу судить, он мало отличается от исходной формы.

При всём этом разнобое в терминологии неудивительно, что на вопрос о том, был ли язык разговорным, даются взаимоисключающие ответы. На самом деле просто надо уточнить, о каком из "церковнославянских" идёт речь. Современный богослужебный язык, разумеется, никогда не был разговорным. Но его предок - исходный ЦСЯ, он же древнеболгарский, таковым являлся для весьма значительной части славян, да и остальные его понимали.

Comment: С самого начала старославянский был языком книжно-литературным и никогда не использовался в качестве средства бытового общения. Но он был понятен всем славянам, т.к. отражал тогдашнее состояние распада праславянской языковой общности. Древнерусский язык не был диалектом старославянского, потому что относится к вост.-слав. группе, в то время как старославянский - к юж.-славянской. Правильнее все же говорить, что на территориях восточных славян использовался старославянский язык древнерусского извода (разновидность текста рукописного памятника, устанавливаемая на основании особенностей языка).

Comment: Тогда вам придётся точно определиться с тем, какой язык называете старославянским. Если совремнный - то да, только "начало" у него несколько столетий назад. А во аремена Кирилла и Мефодия язык не мог быть книжным, ибо письменности не было. В то что молунские братья **создали** язык я, простите, не верю

Comment: И как вы называете язык, который как раз и распадался на три большие группы, в момент о котором мы и говорим сейчас? Я не знаю термина, иного чем старославянский или древнеславянский. Праслявянский - это язык славян до пятого примерно века, гипотетический протославянский - язык баотославянской общности, ещё более дрений. Волей-неволей приходится признать, что славяне таки говорили на старославянском, а древнерусский был его диаоктом.

Comment: „В IX веке славянские языки, по мнению А. Мейе, Н. С. Трубецкого и Н. Н. Дурново, были еще настолько структурно близки друг к другу, что сохраняли общее состояние ПРАСЛАВЯНСКОГО языка позднего периода“. (В.В.Виноградов)