# Древнерусский и старославянский языки

Tags: недопустимая-метка, история

Вопрос по следам предыдущего.
[Какие труды необходимо изучить для знакомства с системой древнерусского языка?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429897)
и еще одного.
[О старославянских языках](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/)

В теме первого из них я высказал мнение, что различия между старославянским и древнерусским языком минимальны. Во всяком случае для начального этапа не стоит отказываться от изучения грамматики церковнославянского потому, что это не русский. Во всяком случае сохранившиеся письменные тексты не дают основания считать языки разными. Они написаны на так называемом древнерусском изводе церковнославянского языка. Обычно его и принимают за древнерусский.

Мне возразили, что дескать, это разные языки. Но к сожалению, не было даже попытки ответить на вопрос, в чем принципиальное отличия и в чем я был неправ, порекомендовав изучать именно ЦСЯ, как язык с имеющейся моделью грамматики.

Может здесь кто-то ответит содержательнее.

Сразу скажу, что известные отличия - отличия в полногласии и в отдельных падежных формах (ехъ-яхъ в местном множественного, например), мне известны. 
Еще кто-то может назвать сколько-нибудь принципиальные различия в грамматике или хотя бы в фонетике?

Answer (score 4):

Как бы то ни было, но это действительно разные языки. Древнерусский язык относится к восточнославянским языкам, старославянский - к южнославянским.

Древнерусский язык был живым языком, развивавшимся по своей внутренней логике и в конечном счёте распавшийся на три восточнославянских языка: русский, белорусский и украинский. Старославянский язык к самого начала был искусственным языком, созданным на основе ограниченного количества южнославянских диалектов своего времени, в него были механически перенесены из греческого и некоторые формы словообразования, и синтаксические конструкции. У старославянского и древнерусского есть много общих черт, но есть и различия. И фонетические, и лексические, и грамматические.

Например, в сочетаниях с плавными звуками (л, р) редуцированные звуки ъ и ь между согласными в старославянском языке не произносились (произносился слоговой плавный – [трoгъ, смрoть]) , а в русском ъ и ь произносились перед плавными (древнерусские търгъ, смьрть, из которых получились современные слова торг и смерть.

По-разному шло падение редуцированных, откуда пошло полногласие в русских словах  и неполногласие в старославянизмах.  Неодинаковыми фонетическими изменениями объясняются и такие соотношения, как старославянские жд, щ – русские ж, ч (в случаях типа чуждый – чужой, мощь – мочь, ср. мочи нет) , начальные ра, ла, е в соответствии с русскими ро, ло, о (равный – ровный, ладья – лодка, единый – один) и др.

Заимствованиями из старославянского  являются слова с некоторыми приставками и суффиксами: пре-, чре-, из-, низ-; -ущ-, -ющ-, -ащ-, -ящ-, -знь-, -ын-, -тв-, -ствий-, -чий-, -тай-.

Лексическое заимствование из старославянского – обоняние –  об + воняти (пахнуть) – от слова воня (не вонь!) – запах вообще; ср.: благовоние, зловоние; ср. смрад – вонь).

Одни старославянизмы вытеснили однокоренные русские слова (сладкий, влажный, охрана, враг, храбрый, жажда и др.); другие разошлись по своему лексическому значению с исконно русскими словами (невежда – невежа, гражданин – горожанин, прах – порох, чуждый – чужой, совратить – своротить, влачить – волочить и др.); третьи вытеснены из русского языка исконно русскими словами (глас, злато, брада, чрево (живот), нощь и др.).

Так что это разные языки, хотя письменный русский (литературный) развивался на основе старославянского(ц.-славянского). Для начинающего изучать древнерусский лучше бы учить именно древнерусский, чтобы не путаться.